# Pass constant in CakePHP 3 routing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my CakePHP 3 application I have a route configured as below

```
$routes->connect(
        '/search-cars-for-dealers/:id',
        [
            'controller' => 'Cars',
            'action' => 'view',
        ],
        [
            'pass' => ['id', 'searchCarsForDealers']
        ]
    );
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass two parameters to the controller action. The first being `id` which is obtained from the original request URL and the second is a constant string - searchCarsForDealers

However, Cake doesnt pass the constant string. It only passes id and passes NULL for the second parameter. So my question is - how can I pass constant strings based on the routing URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass further parameters, then you have to define them in the `$defaults` argument, ie

```
$routes->connect(
    '/search-cars-for-dealers/:id',
    [
        'controller' => 'Cars',
        'action' => 'view',
        'searchCarsForDealers'
    ],
    [
        'pass' => ['id']
    ]
);
```

That way `searchCarsForDealers` will end up as the second argument passed to the `view` action.

It should be noted that this will affect reverse routing, so that you cannot use URL arrays like

```
[
    'controller' => 'Cars',
    'action' => 'view',
    123
]
```

anymore, but have to define the `id` value as a named argument, and also add the `searchCarsForDealers` string, like

```
[
    'controller' => 'Cars',
    'action' => 'view',
    'id' => 123,
    'searchCarsForDealers'
]
```

See also  **[Cookbook > Routing > Connecting Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration)**